# Transpose in Unix

Tags: awk, sed, transpose

I have an hourly data in file this way

```
2015-09-03 02:00:00 to 2015-09-03 02:59:59|ABC|673
2015-09-03 02:00:00 to 2015-09-03 02:59:59|AABC|52
2015-09-03 02:00:00 to 2015-09-03 02:59:59|ABCD|787
2015-09-03 02:00:00 to 2015-09-03 02:59:59|ADFGE|35
2015-09-03 02:00:00 to 2015-09-03 02:59:59|AGER|41
2015-09-03 02:00:00 to 2015-09-03 02:59:59|ETECFF|1384
2015-09-03 02:00:00 to 2015-09-03 02:59:59|TRIFD|38
2015-09-03 02:00:00 to 2015-09-03 02:59:59|CVGFFHG|166
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|FJREER|36
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|DFSD|31
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|ASBF|38
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|ABC|36
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|AABC|35
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|ABCD|33
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|ADFGE|39
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|AGER|33
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|ETECFF|537
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|TRIFD|620635
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|ABC|37
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|AABC|702
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|ABCD|319
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|ADFGE|33
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|AGER|306
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|ETECFF|34
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|TRIFD|44
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|CVGFFHG|599
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|FJREER|30
2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59|DFSD|82
```

I want to transpose the data,

```
1. Column 1 should go in as column header 
2. Column 2 should go in row header
3. Column 3 is data
4. Any absence of data should be represented as 0 (Zero)
```

Here is how the transposed data should look like

```
|2015-09-03 02:00:00 to 2015-09-03 02:59:59|2015-09-03 03:00:00 to 2015-09-03 03:59:59
AABC|52|737
ABC|0|73
ABCD|787|352
ADFGE|35|72
AGER|41|339
ASBF|0|38
CVGFFHG|166|599
DFSD|0|113
ETECFF|1384|571
FJREER|0|66
TRIFD|38|620679
```

I have tried using sed, but that does not work. I am not quite good in awk yet, not yet reached to advanced level, so needed help here

Comment: Where do the numbers come from? Not all seems to match the numbers from the input.

Comment: Also pivot sum seems required.

Comment: thats correct, Sum is required after pivoting.

Comment: ABC|673, ABC|36 and ABC|37 should become : ABC|0|73

Comment: 1) ABC|673, ABC|36 and ABC|37 should become : ABC|0|73 but AABC|52, AABC|35 and AABC|702 should become : AABC|52|737. Could you explain why this is not ABC|673|73.
2) In 4th assertion you write about absence of data. Which line in your data is concerned with ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with awk. It holds in 2D array `values` the sum for
all rows with the same keyword `key` and the same header column index `i`.
At the `END` all these are printed for each key and column.
Array `cols` is used to detect a change of header column.
`hdrs` is used to keep the headers in the right order for output.
`keys` is just used to keep a list of all the keywords.

```
awk -F'|' '
{ hdr = $1; key = $2; val = $3;
  if(cols[hdr]==0){
    cols[hdr] = ++column;
    hdrs[column] = hdr;
  }
  i = cols[hdr]
  keys[key] = 1
  values[i, key] += val
}
END{
  for(i = 1;i<=column;i++)
   printf  "|%s", hdrs[i]
  printf "\n"
  n = asorti(keys,sort)
  for(j = 1;j<=n;j++){
     key = sort[j]
     printf "%s",key
     for(i = 1;i<=column;i++)
      printf "|%s", values[i, key]+0
     printf "\n"
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in awk you can create an array with index of type string, aka a dictionary with column 1 as key.

Each element of that array should be filled with another array with index string: column 2 as key.

Then process each line, creating the new array elements when necessary, and adding column 3 to the value.

For help with the syntax in awk:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/awk-arrays-explained-with-5-practical-examples/

Look at example 1 in section 5 how easy the final solution can be.

Answer (score 0):

another awk

```
awk -F '|' '
  {
  Data[ $1, $2] = $3 + 1
  if( match( Headers, "(^\||)" $1 "(|\|$)" ) == 0 ) Headers = Headers $1 "|"
  if( match( Records, "(^\||)" $2 "(|\|$)" ) == 0 ) Records = Records $2 "|"
  }
END {
  cHeader = split( Headers, aHeader, "|" )
  cRecord = split( Records, aRecord, "|" )

  sub( /\|$/, "", Headers
  print "|" Headers

  for( iRecord = 1; iRecord <= cRecord; iRecord++) {
     printf "%s", aRecord[ 1]
     for( iHeader = 2; iHeader <= cHeader; iHeader++ ) {
        ThisData = Data[ aHeader[ iHeader], aRecord[ iRecord] ]
        printf "|%s", --ThisData
        }
     print
     }
  }
' YourFile
```

- use a string as row and column name reminder and *muti dimensionnal* array for data.
- use `$3 + 1` and later `--ThisData` for forcing the 0